# Change gameobject sprite from other scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new and learning coding. How do I change a sprite from another game scene through a buttoned code.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerChoice : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject plo;
  public Sprite boy;
  public Sprite girl;

  public void Boy()
  {
    plo.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = boy;
  }

  public void Girl()
  {
    plo.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = girl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't do it the way you are trying.
This is a bit tricky for a beginner and you would have to read a bit to get behind it.
This is some starting point where you can dive in:

You would have to to make a gameobject that lives between scenes with

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(targetGameObject);
```

see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

On this gameobject you could have a script which holds all variables that are needed in the next scene.
When scenes are switched access that object and get your values;

Comment: Should have been more precise, sorry. He can't have a cross scene reference and change the values as he is trying to do.